# Which property in manifest.json takes care of this extensions image (screenshot included)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

[image: Missing iamge]

Which property in `manifest.json` file takes care of this missing iamge?

This is my manifest file.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Youtube.md",
  "version": "1.0.2",

  "description": "Create markdown code for Youtube videos",
  "icons": { "16": "icons/icon16.png",
             "48": "icons/icon48.png",
            "128": "icons/icon128.png" },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icons/icon19.png",
      "38": "icons/icon38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Youtube.md",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "author": "Jason Kim",

  "permissions": [
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon48.png"
  }
```

[`icons["48"]`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/icons.html) is responsible for the image at `chrome://extensions`.
When you set a new icon, you have to reload the extension, close the tab and re-open `chrome://extensions` to see the new icon.

Comment: My 48px image was corrupted for some reason. Thank you.